# How to Correctly handle Weak Self in Swift Blocks with Arguments

Tags: ios, swift, retain-cycle

In my `TextViewTableViewCell`, I have a variable to keep track of a block and a configure method where the block is passed in and assigned.
Here is my `TextViewTableViewCell` class:

```
//
//  TextViewTableViewCell.swift
//

import UIKit

class TextViewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textView : UITextView

    var onTextViewEditClosure : ((text : String) -> Void)?

    func configure(#text: String?, onTextEdit : ((text : String) -> Void)) {
        onTextViewEditClosure = onTextEdit
        textView.delegate = self
        textView.text = text
    }

    // #pragma mark - Text View Delegate

    func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView!) {
        if onTextViewEditClosure {
            onTextViewEditClosure!(text: textView.text)
        }
    }
}
```

When I use the configure method in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, how do I properly use weak self in the block that I pass in.
Here is what I have without the weak self:

```
let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textViewCellIdenfitier) as TextViewTableViewCell
myCell.configure(text: body, onTextEdit: {(text: String) in
   // THIS SELF NEEDS TO BE WEAK  
   self.body = text
})
cell = bodyCell
```

**UPDATE**: I got the following to work using `[weak self]`:

```
let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textViewCellIdenfitier) as TextViewTableViewCell
myCell.configure(text: body, onTextEdit: {[weak self] (text: String) in
        if let strongSelf = self {
             strongSelf.body = text
        }
})
cell = myCell
```

When I do `[unowned self]` instead of `[weak self]` and take out the `if` statement, the app crashes. Any ideas on how this should work with `[unowned self]`?

Comment: Could you select an answer below as the correct answer then? Also note that with unowned you wouldn't need to strongify self within your closure. Unowned is better than weak here because the life cycle of your cell and view controller are linked.

Comment: I realize that [unowned self] if the better option, but my app crashes when I use it. Would love to see a code sample using it to close out the answer.

Comment: From the docs: "Like weak references, an unowned reference does not keep a strong hold on the instance it refers to. Unlike a weak reference, however, an unowned reference is assumed to always have a value. "  If your app crashes, it's likely because unowned is being applied to a value that's nil at runtime.

Comment: Probably better to advertise a guard statement here than if let binding to strongSelf. Just saying, this is like the perfect candidate :-D

Comment: @NatashaTheRobot, What syntax is [weak self] ?. looks like a message passing in objective C. Can you please add a little bit more about the syntax in the question please.

Comment: Instead of `if let strongSelf = self { strongSelf.body = text }` you should use `self?.body = text`. Shorter, clearer.

Comment: Or "guard let `self` = self else { return }" if you have a bigger logic and want to avoid nesting.

Comment: Rather to your question you are still creating retain cycle while giving self to you TextView delegate

Comment: @Ricardo In a situation when I do use ```[weak self] in```, and then ```guard let `self` = self else { return }```, what would happen following the guard statement if the guard test succeeds? Would it be possible for the strong self after the guard statement to point to memory that has been released and thus cause a crash?

Comment: No, because you are retaining it, that's why it is called strong. A dangling pointer is not possible in that case.

Answer (score 190):

If **self** could be nil in the closure use **[weak self]**.

If **self** will never be nil in the closure use **[unowned self]**.

If it's crashing when you use **[unowned self]** I would guess that self is nil at some point in that closure, which is why you had to go with **[weak self]** instead.

I really liked the whole section from the manual on using **strong**, **weak**, and **unowned** in closures:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

*Note: I used the term **closure** instead of **block** which is the newer Swift term:*

[Difference between block (Objective C) and closure (Swift) in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26374792/difference-between-block-objective-c-and-closure-swift-in-ios)

Comment: Apple called blocks "closures" in their very first document for a C language extension. (Blocks or closures are an extension of C at the very first. Only MM is related to Objective-C.) Even I prefer the term "closure", too, because "blocks" in C is related to compound statements very often, it is a kind of wrong in both languages, because it is called a closure even it does not close over an object (variable or constant).

Comment: very nicely answered :)

Comment: I would suggest never using `unowned`. Its not worth the risk of causing your app to crash.

Answer (score 38):

**EDITED for Swift 4.2:

As @Koen commented, swift 4.2 allows:

```
guard let self = self else {
   return // Could not get a strong reference for self :`(
}

// Now self is a strong reference
self.doSomething()
```

P.S.: Since I am having some up-votes, I would like to recommend the reading about [escaping closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID546).

<s>EDITED: As @tim-vermeulen has commented, Chris Lattner said on Fri Jan 22 19:51:29 CST 2016, this trick should not be used on self, so please don't use it. Check the non escaping closures info and the capture list answer from @gbk.**</s>

For those who use [weak self] in capture list, note that self could be nil, so the first thing I do is check that with a guard statement

```
guard let `self` = self else {
   return
}
self.doSomething()
```

If you are wondering what the quote marks are around `self` is a pro trick to use self inside the closure without needing to change the name to *this*, *weakSelf* or whatever.

Comment: I prefer to this answer, what a neat solution!

Comment: ` self `
is a sample of shadowing, an article about it can be found here http://arsenkin.com/swift-closure-without-ugly-strongSelf.html

Comment: Nice! Awesome find!

Comment: Nice! but '@noescape' doesnt work for typealiased closures. So have to use 'self' thing as u suggested.

Comment: I tend to call the local "self" "strongSelf" to make sure it's not confused with the default self and is easier to spot whether you've guarded for a strong self reference.

Comment: This should not be used, as it is a compiler bug: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160118/007425.html

Comment: I think the comment by Chris Lattner in above link is just about not naming the variable as `self` (in backticks). Name it something else such as nonOptionalSelf and it will be fine.

Comment: Nowadays (swift 4.2) `{ [weak self] in guard let self = self else { return }` can be used without backticks, and is actually supported: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0079-upgrade-self-from-weak-to-strong.md#proposed-solution

Comment: @Koen. In that case, doesn't the closure continue to run until it comes to an end, at which time strong self releases the object. Is there a way to use a weak self in the closure so that at any time during the execution process of the closure the object is released by all other strong references, the weak self becomes nil and the closure stops executing in the middle of processing?

Comment: @Koen. When I use weak self as in this code: interactiveQueue.async { [weak self] in self?.intNumber += 1 }, sometimes I get an error saying the optional self needs to be unwrapped by using a !

Comment: I noticed I get that error when using a for-in loop, such as { [weak self] in for item in self?.arrayOfItems }.

Answer (score 36):

**EDIT: Reference to an updated solution by LightMan**

See [LightMan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38635240/1121497). Until now I was using:

```
input.action = { [weak self] value in
    guard let this = self else { return }
    this.someCall(value) // 'this' isn't nil
}
```

Or:

```
input.action = { [weak self] value in
    self?.someCall(value) // call is done if self isn't nil
}
```

Usually you don't need to specify the parameter type if it's inferred.

You can omit the parameter altogether if there is none or if you refer to it as `$0` in the closure:

```
input.action = { [weak self] in
    self?.someCall($0) // call is done if self isn't nil
}
```

Just for completeness; if you're passing the closure to a function and the parameter is not `@escaping`, you don't need a `weak self`:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].forEach { self.someCall($0) }
```

Answer (score 34):

Put `[unowned self]` before `(text: String)...` in your closure. This is called a *capture list* and places ownership instructions on symbols captured in the closure.

Comment: Thanks for naming it, I wanted to know that!

Comment: I don't think this answer is useful. [unowned self] will crash if self becomes nil during the execution of closure

Comment: there is **absolutely no reason** to use unowned, other than (1) in *extremely* unusual situations, for performance (this is utterly irrelevant here and in 99.999% of programming) and (2) as a style-enforcement matter.  The statement "You should always use weak, never unowned" is very reasonable.

Answer (score 28):

Use [Capture list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

> **Defining a Capture List**
>
> Each item in a capture list is a pairing of the weak or unowned
>   keyword with a reference to a class instance (such as self) or a
>   variable initialized with some value (such as delegate =
>   self.delegate!). These pairings are written within a pair of square
>   braces, separated by commas.
>
> Place the capture list before a closure’s parameter list and return
>   type if they are provided:

```
lazy var someClosure: (Int, String) -> String = {
    [unowned self, weak delegate = self.delegate!] (index: Int, stringToProcess: String) -> String in
    // closure body goes here 
}
```

> If a closure does not specify a parameter list or return type because
>   they can be inferred from
>   context, place the capture list at the very start of the closure,
>   followed by the in keyword:

```
lazy var someClosure: Void -> String = {
    [unowned self, weak delegate = self.delegate!] in
    // closure body goes here
}
```

[additional explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24045189/2012219)

Comment: You used unowned for "self" which means you know for sure "self" wont be nil when you access it. 
Then you used force unwrap on "self.delegate" (which also means you know for sure it wont be nil) to assign it to a weak var. 
If you know for sure that "self.delegate" wont be nil, why not using unowned on the "delegate" instead of weak?

Answer (score 16):

#### As of swift 4.2  we can do:

```
_ = { [weak self] value in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    print(self) // will never be nil
}()
```

Comment: Others have similar solutions, but "this" is C++ IMHO. "strongSelf" is a Apple convention and anyone who glances at your code will know whats going on.

Comment: @ David H IMO the phrase `strongSelf` explicitly explains the variables meaning/sideeffect which is nice if the code is of a more lengthy nature. appreciate your opinion though, did not know c++ used such phrasing.

Comment: As of Swift 4.2 you can use `guard let self = self else { return }` to unwrap `[weak self]` : https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0079-upgrade-self-from-weak-to-strong.md

Comment: @AmerHukic  .

Comment: Nice but you are not using `value` and if value is a model reference how you can use it?

Comment: You are right @Naresh the value is not used in this example. Can be taken out.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4.2**

```
let closure = { [weak self] (_ parameter:Int) in
    guard let self = self else { return }

    self.method(parameter)
}
```

https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0079-upgrade-self-from-weak-to-strong.md

Answer (score 3):

You can use [weak self] or [unowned self] in the capture list prior to your parameters of the block.  The capture list is optional syntax.

`[unowned self]` works good here because the cell will never be nil.  Otherwise you can use `[weak self]`

Comment: the cell is not self , he is not on the cell class, he is probably on a viewcontroller...

Answer (score 1):

[[Closure and strong reference cycles]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61020491/4770877)

As you know Swift's closure can capture the instance. It means that you are able to  use `self` inside a closure. Especially `escaping closure`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60990583/4770877) can create a `strong reference cycle`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61020491/4770877). By the way you have to explicitly use `self` inside `escaping closure`.

Swift closure has `Capture List` feature which allows you to avoid such situation and break a reference cycle because do not have a strong reference to captured instance. Capture List element is a pair of `weak`/`unowned` and a reference to class or variable.

For example

```
class A {
    private var completionHandler: (() -> Void)!
    private var completionHandler2: ((String) -> Bool)!
    
    func nonescapingClosure(completionHandler: () -> Void) {
        print("Hello World")
    }
    
    func escapingClosure(completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.completionHandler = completionHandler
    }
    
    func escapingClosureWithPArameter(completionHandler: @escaping (String) -> Bool) {
        self.completionHandler2 = completionHandler
    }
}

class B {
    var variable = "Var"
    
    func foo() {
        let a = A()
        
        //nonescapingClosure
        a.nonescapingClosure {
            variable = "nonescapingClosure"
        }
        
        //escapingClosure
        //strong reference cycle
        a.escapingClosure {
            self.variable = "escapingClosure"
        }
        
        //Capture List - [weak self]
        a.escapingClosure {[weak self] in
            self?.variable = "escapingClosure"
        }
        
        //Capture List - [unowned self]
        a.escapingClosure {[unowned self] in
            self.variable = "escapingClosure"
        }
        
        //escapingClosureWithPArameter
        a.escapingClosureWithPArameter { [weak self] (str) -> Bool in
            self?.variable = "escapingClosureWithPArameter"
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

- `weak` - more preferable, use it when it is **possible**
- `unowned` - use it when you are sure that lifetime of instance owner is bigger than closure

[[weak vs unowned]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61020491/4770877)

Answer (score 0):

If you are crashing than you probably need [weak self]

My guess is that the block you are creating is somehow still wired up.

Create a prepareForReuse and try clearing the onTextViewEditClosure block inside that.

```
func prepareForResuse() {
   onTextViewEditClosure = nil
   textView.delegate = nil
}
```

See if that prevents the crash.  (It's just a guess).

Answer (score 0):

From `Swift 5.3`, you do not have to unwrap `self` in closure if you pass `[self]` before `in` in closure.

Refer `someFunctionWithEscapingClosure { [self] in x = 100 }` in [this swift doc](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question as using `[self]` is a strong capture of self