# Realm notifications that capture [weak self] in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

In the Realm documentation for Swift, the section on [notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications) has this sample code:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
  var notificationToken: NotificationToken? = nil

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let results = realm.objects(Person.self).filter("age > 5")

    // Observe Results Notifications
    notificationToken = results.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
      guard let tableView = self?.tableView else { return }
      // ... some code removed here ...
    }
  }

  deinit {
    // notificationToken?.invalidate() in Realm 10.12
    notificationToken?.stop()
  }
}
```

I was wondering why `[weak self]` is used here instead of `[unowned self]`. In what use case could `self` be nil here? (before reaching `deinit`)

Comment: Apple said "Use a weak reference whenever it is valid for that reference to become nil at some point during its lifetime. Conversely, use an unowned reference when you know that the reference will never be nil once it has been set during initialization."

Comment: maybe your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468336/how-to-correctly-handle-weak-self-in-swift-blocks-with-arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific case it cannot be ever `nil` because the notification block will never be called after `stop()` is called, and `unowned` would be fine. The use of `weak` is just to make it more robust in the case where someone copies and pastes the code into a seemingly similar situation which does not actually guarantee that `self` will never be `nil`.