# Should l I use [unowned self] for Realm.write()?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have some weird memory issues in an app and I'm wondering if I'm doing the correct thing here. I use Realm and have e.g:

```
try! self.realm.write {
    self.realm.add(newItem)
}
```

But I'm wondering if I'm causing a retain cycle inadvertently so should maybe do:

```
try! self.realm.write { [unowned self] in
    self.realm.add(newItem)
}
```

Which would be correct and why?

Comment: unowned change to weak ```[weak self]```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525752/realm-notifications-that-capture-weak-self-in-swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a look at the `write` method declaration, you will see, that the closure is non escaping. So, you don't need to use neither `weak` nor `unowned`. It will not lead to retain cycle.

```
public func write(_ block: (() throws -> Void)) throws {
    beginWrite()
    do {
        try block()
    } catch let error {
        if isInWriteTransaction { cancelWrite() }
        throw error
    }
    if isInWriteTransaction { try commitWrite() }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about realm I would suggest using `weak self` in case that self might be nil.

```
try! self.realm.write { [weak self] in
    self?.realm.add(newItem)
}
```

and maybe try to avoid using `!` for the try part and instead handle a possible error case properly.

Comment: Your code will not compile because of optional self. The note about `!` is good (describing [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#writes): _For brevity, our code samples don’t handle these errors, but you certainly should in your production applications._)

Comment: @pacification thanks for the comment, fixed the code