# Why Swift closure not capture self?

Tags: swift, closures, automatic-ref-counting

I was testing swift closure with Xcode playground.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class A{
    var closure: ()->() = {}

    var name: String = "A"
    init() {
        self.closure = {
            self.name = self.name + " Plus"
        }
    }

    deinit {
        print(name + " is deinit")
    }
}

var a: A?
a = A()
a = nil
```

As what is expected, a is self contained by closure, so a is never released.

But, when I add this line before the last line:

```
a?.closure = { a?.name = "ttt" }
```

Then, I found "A is deinit" in the output window, which means a is released.
Why? is a not recycle reference?

To be test, I use a function to set the closure, which the code is version 2:

```
import UIKit

class A{
    var closure: ()->() = {}
    func funcToSetClosure(){
        self.closure = { self.name = "BBB"}
    }
    var name: String = "A"
    init() {
        self.closure = {
            self.name = self.name + " Plus"
        }
    }

    deinit {
        print(name + " is deinit")
    }
}



var a: A?


a = A()


a?.funcToSetClosure()


a = nil
```

Again, a is never released.

So I got the conclusion, when closure is set by init or a function in the class, it will cause recycle reference, when it is set out side the class, it will not cause recycle reference. Am I right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are retain cycles in both cases. The difference is the nature of the *reference*, not the *place* where `closure` is set. This difference is manifested in what it takes to *break* the cycle:

- In the "inside" situation, the reference inside the closure is `self`. When you release your reference to `a`, that is *insufficient* to break the cycle, because the cycle is directly self-referential. To break the cycle, you would have had *also* to set `a.closure` to `nil` before setting `a` to `nil`, and you didn't do that.

[image]

- In the "outside" situation, the reference is `a`. There is a retain cycle so long as your `a` reference is not set to `nil`. But you eventually *do* set it to `nil`, which *is* sufficient to break the cycle.

[image]

(Illustrations come from Xcode's memory graph feature. So cool.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, finally I understand, and thanks for Xcode's memory graph too.

Answer (score 3):

As the [SIL documentation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/SIL.rst#box-types) says, when you capture a local variable in a closure, it will be stored on the heap with reference counting:

> Captured local variables and the payloads of `indirect` value types are
>   stored on the heap. The type `@box T` is a reference-counted type that
>   references a box containing a mutable value of type `T`.

Therefore when you say:

```
var a : A? = A()
a?.closure = { a?.name = "ttt" }
```

you *do* have a reference cycle (which you can easily verify). This is because the instance of `A` has a reference to the `closure` property, which has a reference to the heap-allocated boxed `A?` instance (due to the fact that it's being captured by the closure), which in turn has a reference to the instance of `A`.

However, you then say:

```
a = nil
```

Which sets the heap-allocated boxed `A?` instance's value to `.none`, thus releasing its reference to the instance of `A`, therefore meaning that you no longer have a reference cycle, and thus `A` can be deallocated.

Just letting `a` fall out of scope without assigning `a = nil` will *not* break the reference cycle, as the instance of `A?` on the heap is still being retained by the `closure` property of `A`, which is still being retained by the `A?` instance.

Answer (score 2):

What causes the retain cycle is that you reference `self` in the closure.

```
var a: A?
a = A()
a?.closure = { a?.name = "ttt" }
a = nil
```

You change the closure to no longer reference `self`, that's why it is deallocated.

In the final example, you make it reference `self` again in the closure, that is why it does not deallocate. There are ways around this, this post is a great list of when to use each case in swift: [How to Correctly handle Weak Self in Swift Blocks with Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468336/how-to-correctly-handle-weak-self-in-swift-blocks-with-arguments)

I would imagine you are looking for something like this, where you use a weak reference to self inside the block. Swift has some new ways to do this, most commonly using the `[unowned self]` notation at the front of the block.

```
init() {
    self.closure = { [unowned self] in
        self.name = self.name + " Plus"
    }
}
```

More reading on what is going on here: [Shall we always use [unowned self] inside closure in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320347/shall-we-always-use-unowned-self-inside-closure-in-swift)