# Does values capturing of closure in swift means creating static variable?

Tags: swift, closures

In **Capturing Values** section of [swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94):

> ... It does this by capturing a reference to runningTotal and amount from the surrounding function and using them within its own function body. ...

and

> If you create a second incrementer, it will have its own stored reference to a new, separate runningTotal variable.

So I try the following testing and get a conclusion that since each incrementer made by the `makeIncrementer(forIncrementer:)` has its own `runningTotal` and the value of `runningTotal` is **remembered** by each incrementer, what values-capturing does is equivalent to creating some static variable(s) for a closure. But I'm not sure whether my statement is correct.

```
func makeIncrementer(forIncrement amount: Int) -> () -> Int {
    var runningTotal = 0
    func incrementer() -> Int {
        runningTotal += amount
        return runningTotal
    }

    return incrementer
}

let by10Incrementer = makeIncrementer(forIncrement: 10)
let by20Incrementer = makeIncrementer(forIncrement: 20)

for i in 0..<5 {
    print(by10Incrementer())
}

print("---")

for j in 0..<5 {
    print(by20Incrementer())
}
```

output:

```
10
20
30
40
50
---
20
40
60
80
100
```

I originally thought that the output of `by20Incrementer()` would start from 50, but it starts from 0. So the `runningTotal` of each incrementer refers to different one.

Comment: Captured values are put into reference-counted boxes on the heap, which are then stored on the function's context object (although as an optimisation, can be stack-promoted in some cases) – compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/40979548/2976878 & (if you're interested in the nitty gritty details) https://stackoverflow.com/q/43171341/2976878.

Comment: FWIW, it helps me to think of functions as a Type rather than a traditional function.

Answer (score 4):

Captures do not become static in a closure, in the sense that each instance of the closure gets its own copy of the variable.

> I originally thought that the output of `by20Incrementer()` would start from 50, but it starts from 0

It starts from the value of `runningTotal` at the time the closure is created, which is always zero. No matter how many times you increment `runningTotal` in `by10Incrementer`, it wouldn't change the value of `runningTotal` captured in `by20Incrementer`, because it is a different instance with its own capture of `runningTotal`.

Effectively, `runningTotal` becomes a `var` on the object that represents the closure. Swift syntax makes this capture implicit, but internally the variable is there.