# Captured weak reference pointed to wrong object

Tags: swift, closures, weak-references

If I weakly reference self in a closure:

```
{[weak self] in self!.doSomethinmg()}
```

And `self` is deallocated, yet the closure continues to exist. Is it possible that `self` in the closure can become non-nil at some point in the future -- pointing to some random new object as determined by the runtime environment?

Comment: You should not force-unwrap self in the first place.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, but if a weak reference can end up pointing to a different object entirely, then it doesn't even matter if you check if it's non-nil, because it will be non-nil, but also not what it was intended to be.

Comment: The weak reference is set to `nil` when the pointed-to object is deallocated.

Comment: @shoe for  example if you are calling webservice using alamofire. before you get the response. you dismiss \ pop view controller . results your `self` will be `nil`  and you are doing some UI setup like setting labels, or tables then your app will crash. using weak / unowned self you make sure about proper deallocation of object as well as be safer for such a crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the `strong` references to an instance are removed, then the instance will eventually be deallocated. But that doesn't necessarily mean the references that were referring to it will be reused. All the `strong` references are obviously gone because they had to be in order for it to be deallocated in the first place. So whatever that means for the memory that those references required for their referring duties is irrelevant to the application, because the references don't exist anywhere in it anymore.

Which leaves `unowned` and `weak` references left. [Apple makes it pretty clear](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID48) that attempting to access the value of an `unowned` reference after the instance has been deallocated is a no, no:

> If you try to access the value of an unowned reference after that instance has been deallocated, you’ll get a runtime error.

So that is also irrelevant to the application, simply because it's a hard-rule not to be broken.

Which leaves, last but not least, `weak` references. [Apple says this about weak references](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID48):

> Because a weak reference does not keep a strong hold on the instance
>   it refers to, it’s possible for that instance to be deallocated while
>   the weak reference is still referring to it. Therefore, ARC
>   automatically sets a weak reference to nil when the instance that it
>   refers to is deallocated.
>
> ...
>
> You can check for the existence of a value in the weak reference, just
>   like any other optional value, and you will never end up with a
>   reference to an invalid instance that no longer exists.

The key take away here is that the reference is set to `nil`. And even though `nil` represents nothing, it's still a valid value. And I feel it may be safe to assume that the runtime environment won't steal a reference and use it for another purpose when it's still pointing to a valid value. Imagine what it'd be like otherwise.

So the relevance to the application here for `weak` references is just that they may become `nil` at some point; and as @MartinR showed in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48560116/6744473), this may even happen mid-execution of the closure. So the final solution would seem to be creating a `strong` reference from the `weak` reference before using it, aka the "weak/strong dance":

Either:

```
{ [weak self] in 
    if let strongSelf = self {
        strongSelf.doSomething()
    }
}
```

or

```
{ [weak self] in 
    guard let strongSelf = self else {   return   }
    strongSelf.doSomething()
}
```

If the closure consists of a single optional chain:

```
{ [weak self] in 
    self?.doSomething()
}
```

will simply result in a non-op if `self` is `nil`, but no idea if this bears any guarantee that `self` won't be deallocated mid-execution of the closure if it's arbitrarily longer:

```
{ [weak self] in 
    self?.doSomething()
    ...
    self?.doSomethingDownTheLine()
}
```

So in this case, doing the weak/strong dance will guarantee that your closure will be all-or-nothing:

```
{ [weak self] in 
    guard let strongSelf = self else {   return   }
    strongSelf.doSomething()
    ...
    strongSelf.doSomethingDownTheLine()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A pointer is a variable whose value is a memory address. The same is
true for a *weak pointer,* but the value of a weak pointer is
(due to some runtime magic) set to `nil` if the pointed-to object is
deallocated. It is *irrelevant* if any new object is created at the
same memory location later, the weak pointer variable stays `nil`.

So

```
{ [weak self] in /* ... */ }
```

creates a closure with a weak pointer variable. That variable
is set to `nil` when the pointed-to object is deallocated.
That may happen before the closure is called or during the execution
of the closure, so even

```
{ [weak self] in
   if (self != nil) self!.doSomethinmg()
}
```

is unsafe and can crash if the object is deallocated between the test
and the method call.

But at any point, the weak pointer either points to
the original object instance or is `nil`. It will
never point to some other object instance. (That *may* happen with
unowned references.)

As [Lorenzo says,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48559375/1187415) don't
force unwrap the weak pointer. Either use optional chaining or
create a strong reference inside the closure.

Comment: I believe this is the best answer. Also pleas check [this](https://gist.github.com/matkuznik/cfb85d291b13909ac696942982c9ffeb)

Comment: Great answer sir ,This should be accepted answer !!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to achieve.

Martin is suggesting the right thing. In order to guarantee you don't have any crash and continue to deal with that instance you can use `weak`/`strong` dance. Otherwise, use `self?`.

So for example, with the `weak`/`strong` dance you can do the following:

```
{ [weak self] in 
    if let strongSelf = self {
        strongSelf.doSomething()
    }
}
```

Otherwise

```
{ [weak self] in 
    self?.doSomething()
}
```

While in the first case the instance that belongs to `self` will continue to exist until the closure will be discarded, in the second case, instead, since the instance will be put to `nil`, it will behave as a sort of non-op.

Comment: I don't think that there is any difference between the two versions.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327236/is-it-safe-to-force-unwrap-variables-that-have-been-optionally-accessed-in-the-s, in particular @dfri's answer. If `self` is not nil then `self?.doSomething()` keeps the object alive during the method call.

Comment: Agree with @MartinR No difference between two blocks. it is clear example of optional chaining . method will only been executed if self is non nil