# How get data from closure in swift

Tags: swift, post, closures

I new in swift
and I wrote simple api connector to get info from server, but I do not know how to get my data from server and use it in app

```
var account: DriverAccount = DriverAccount()
ApiConnectController.instance().makeAPICall(url: driverAuthUrlEndpoint,
                                                    params:paramsDictionary,
                                                    withAutorization: false,
                                                    method: .POST,
                                                    success: { (data, response, error, json) in
                                                        self.account = try! DriverAccount(json: json!) // Error Closure cannot implicitly capture a mutating self parameter
                                                        print("OK")
        },
                                                    failure: { (data, response, error, json) in
                                                        print("NOT")
        })
```

How to get data into self.account?

```
class DriverAccount {
var callSign: String?
var dispPhone: String?
var isLoggedin:Bool

init() {
    self.callSign = ""
    self.dispPhone = ""
    self.isLoggedin = false
}

init(isLoggedIn logedIn: Bool, withCallSign callsign: String, andDispPhone dispPhone: String) {
    self.callSign = callsign
    self.dispPhone = dispPhone
    self.isLoggedin = logedIn
}
```

}

Comment: Your error is due to driver account being a struct. And you already initialize it before the closure. Maybe you can change the driver account to have a method to fill itself instead of reinit it. So you could do self.account.fill(with: Json)

Comment: Yes it was a struct, change it to class `code` class DriverAccount {
    var callSign: String?
    var dispPhone: String?
    var isLoggedin:Bool
    
    init() {
        self.callSign = ""
        self.dispPhone = ""
        self.isLoggedin = false
    }
    
    init(isLoggedIn logedIn: Bool, withCallSign callsign: String, andDispPhone dispPhone: String) {
        self.callSign = callsign
        self.dispPhone = dispPhone
        self.isLoggedin = logedIn
    }
} `code` But nothing changed ((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think, your DriverAccount is a struct. Structs are values. So, values are copied for reuse in closures and self.account is a let-value in your closure. If you want to change local var in closure, use class. 
And, you can produce retain-cicle if use just a self.. - use ([weak self] in) to avoid it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26598603/5769826

Comment: Yes it was a struct, change it to class, Added into post. But Closure cannot implicitly capture a mutating self parameter Error on same place (