# How to trigger protocol function in a view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, viewcontroller

## `DeviceTableViewCell`

I create a protocol on my custom `DeviceTableViewCell`

```
protocol DeviceTableViewCellDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
    func printMe(_ text : String)
}
```

I also declared my `delegate` in

```
weak var delegate: DeviceTableViewCellDelegate?
```

---

## `DevicesViewController`

I had this

```
extension DevicesViewController: DeviceTableViewCellDelegate {
    
   
    func printMe(_ text : String) {
        let text = "Protocol & Delegate"
        
        print("........")
        print(text)
        print("........")
    }
}
```

---

I don't know how to trigger my print() statement.
How would one trigger it ?

Do I need to call my `printMe()` somewhere ?

Did I missing something here ?

Comment: Which ever class has the `delegate` property (presumable your cell class) must call the `printMe` method at some appropriate time. Only you know how it is to be used and when it should be called.

Comment: You treat a delegate as a placeholder. In future, you can assign any role to this delegate.

Answer (score 0):

First, do this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell
cell.delegate = self
}
```

Then, you must call printMe from your cell to handle your action

Answer (score 0):

You just declare how the delegate function working, you haven't called it yet.
Based on the context, you can decide when to call `delegate.printMe(_ text : "Foo")`.

I suggest a simple example you could refer: [passing data back to previous view controller from current view controller using delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49206013/5560974).

Answer (score 0):

Let's take example to understand the concept. So as you already create delegate variable for your protocol.

```
weak var delegate: DeviceTableViewCellDelegate?
```

Now to call protocol method you need to assign your delegate to some viewController or class. Let's assign in same view controller in viewDidLoad method.

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
   delegate = self
}
```

Now let's say need to call protocol method when some button pressed. So what you need to do is call this method like this in button press method.

```
delegate?.printMe("Button Pressed")
```